# HTML & PHP - How to make multiple forms submittable

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

I have the following code which loops through an array to create forms that are filled with values (which the user will be able to edit) on a single page. There are as many forms as there are loops in the array, which is always changing.

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <?php
    foreach($articles as $item) { ?>
        <div id='container'>
            <form>
                Title: <input type="text" name="title" size="80" value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>">
                <br>
                URL: <input type="text" name="url" size="80" value="<?php echo $item[1]; ?>">
                <br>
                End Date: <input type="text" name="endDate" value="<?php echo substr($item[7], 14, strpos($item[7], '@') - strlen($item[7])); ?>">
                <br>
                <?php
                    if (substr($item[8], 0, 2) === 'Su'){
                    } else {
                ?>
                Start Date: <input type="text" name="startDate" value="<?php echo substr($item[8], 7, 9); ?>">
                <?php } ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Now, I want the user to have a single submit button at the bottom of the page which will submit ALL the forms on the page to MySQL database. The problem is I don't know how to do that.

I know the submit button takes the format of

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I am assuming I need to give each form in the loop a unique name but from there I am at a loss as to what my next step should be to actually send and receive the information from these multiple forms.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with putting all sets of `<input>`s into a single form? You can't submit more than one form at once, your options are AJAX, iFrames or refreshing and submitting (in order of my recommendation)

Comment: How would you suggest I put all the inputs in a single form?

Comment: Take the `<form>` out of the loop.. Ill post an answer for it.

Comment: Does your `$item` array contains the ID of the field in the database?

Comment: The ratio of submit buttons to forms may be greater than 1, but each submit button can only submit one form (absent some bizarre JavaScript hack).  So I agree with the strategy of using one large form and a single submit button.  But be on the lookout for Suhosin, which is a "security feature" that can silently truncate very large forms!

Comment: Btw it's easier to just echo the html code with a single quote(')
Like this echo '<div id="container">';
And it's easier to put the form outside the loop and the submit button after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit more than one form at once. What is wrong with putting all sets of `<input>`s into a single form?:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form>
    <?php
    $inpCnt = 0;
    foreach($articles as $item) {
        $inpCnt++;  ?>
        <div id='container'>
                Title: <input type="text" name="title_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>" size="80" value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>">
                <br>
                URL: <input type="text" name="url_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>" size="80" value="<?php echo $item[1]; ?>">
                <br>
                End Date: <input type="text" name="endDate_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>" value="<?php echo substr($item[7], 14, strpos($item[7], '@') - strlen($item[7])); ?>">
                <br>
                <?php
                    if (substr($item[8], 0, 2) === 'Su'){
                    } else {
                ?>
                Start Date: <input type="text" name="startDate_<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>" value="<?php echo substr($item[8], 7, 9); ?>">
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

You need to be able to define each of these inputs aswel. So I've used the loop to give each one a unique name.

Comment: @jeroen Feel free to elaborate

Comment: You have multiple fields with the same name, only the last one will be in your `$_REQUEST` array.

Comment: That would be a problem indeed. Would an i++ counter work inside a foreach loop?

Comment: You can change them to array named fields- `title[]`, `url[]`, `endDate[]`, `startDate[]`.

Comment: @Jonathan You should change them to arrays but I would use the ID of the database row as the array index to make it easier to handle at the back-end.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the heads up, I've made an update. Sean I did consider that but not knowing what keys have been used I didn't want to suggest it.

Comment: You can get around the multiple fields with same name problem by prefixing your field names with a counter such as.... 

Fn_FIELDNAME

where n is the counter value which you increment directly AFTER your FOR EACH Loop 

I used the letter F to signify FORM which you originally started with so Fn also tells you which FORM it 'would' have been, had you not used an all emcompassing form

Comment: For some reason the answer suggested causes the $inpCnt variable to increment after each input, not each "form". I wind up with title_1, url_2, endDate_3, startDate_4, title_5, etc. instead of title_1, url_1, endDate_1, startDate_1, title_2, etc.

Comment: Figured out why. Need to remove the ++ from the variables in the input names.